# Run a Query Using a Button in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, macros, vba

I am trying to run a query in Access 2010 inside of a form. The form, per user request, needs to have buttons that they can use to quickly change the data in their column. For the table being called, there are only two columns that matter: Equiptment_Name and Amount (The other several columns are just there to help reference the data in case they misspell the name of the product). The current query I have is:

```
UPDATE tblInventory SET Amount = Amount-[Enter Amount]
WHERE ((([tblInventory].Equiptment_Name)=[Enter Name]));
```

This works perfectly, I just can't get it to work in a form with a button. I've searched all over for help and was encouraged to use a macro because that would be the easiest way. Can someone please walk me through the process of getting a macro to run a version of my query? I'm fine with the user being prompted to enter the amount to withdraw from the Amount category, but it would be nice if they didn't have to type in the Equiptment_Name category since The button would be in the form next to it (see picture below). Thanks for all help in advance.

[image]

Comment: You can always save a query and use the name of that query via VBA a couple different ways. Such as handling the `OnClick` event of `Command70` and putting `DoCmd.OpenQuery "YourQueryName"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use VBA to get this going. Something along the lines of

```
Private Sub Command70_Click()
    If Len(Me.AmountTextBoxName & vbNullString) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Amount cannot be empty !", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Len(Me.Equiptment_NameTextBoxName & vbNullString) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Equiptment Name cannot be empty !", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    CurrentDB.Exeucte "UPDATE tblInventory SET Amount = Amount - " & Me.AmountTextBoxName & _
                      "WHERE tblInventory.Equiptment_Name = '" & Me.Equiptment_NameTextBoxName & "';"
End Sub
```

I have taken the Equipment name is actually a String.